# View() Keyboard shortcut for entire pipelines in Rstudio?

Tags: r, view, rstudio

I just got done browsing the keyboard shortcuts for RStudio and I can't find one for View() that works not only for single variables (dataframe) but for entire pipelines.

I'd like to highlight any pipeline like the one below and hit Ctrl+X+Y+Z or whatever to see the spreadsheet view of my data frame in RStudio.

```
mtcars %>%
select(1, 2) %>%
head()
```

Comment: There is no such shortcut at the moment. It looks like someone had suggested that previously but they did not decide to implement it: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3320

Comment: What's your approach for this?